# MOSFET based switch for high voltages

Tags: mosfet, high-voltage

I'm struggling with the design of a MOSFET based switch for high input voltages.
See schematic of the basic circuit that I've come up with:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0FeH0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When M3 would be ON, the voltage on it's drain would be approximately 0.
This also means that M2 Vgs ~= (-50)V, exceeding the AMR for this MOSFET.

MOSFETs can't sustain this kind of high voltage on Vgs... What could be an appropriate solution for this?

Comment: Did you mean to make M3 a P-channel, and M2 an N-channel?

Comment: @Phil Frost: Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you used an N channel MOSFET symbol for M3 and a P type MOSFET symbol for M2.

To solve your dilemma, if you insert a resistor in series with the drain of M3 (n channel device), you should be able to understand that this forms a mechanism for reducing the gate voltage on M2.

Try a 10k\$\Omega\$ resistor and also make R2 about 10k\$\Omega\$. Now you only get 25V on the gate. If that is too much make R2 smaller like 3k3 - now you'll only get 12.4V on the gate.

And if you need the same circuit to run from a 15V supply, leave R2 as 100k\$\Omega\$ and put a 12V zener across it, cathode to positive rail.

Comment: Wouldn't having a resistor in series with the drain of M3 make the OFF to ON transition of M2 slower? Slower transition of M2 with a high load current could ruin M2...?

Comment: @dor With 3k3 on the upper transistor's gate and (say) a gate capacitance of 1nF, the CR time will be 3.3usecs and likely not to cause power dissipation problems with M2. If the OP was proposing a PWM circuit then yes, something would need to be done.

Comment: @dor how fast do you need it to be? This would be a good requirement to specify in the question.

Comment: @Phil Frost: I don't need it to be fast, but I'm interested in a generic design that suits to high load current.